# how to place 2 figures and controlling the space between them if I am using IEEEtran package

Tags: ieeetran

I am new with LaTeX and struggling with placing 2 figures in one page. I want to place one figure at the top of the page and place another figure at the bottom of the first figure, that is, one figure in a row. I also want to reduce the size of the space between the figure and the caption. By the way I am using: `\documentclass[journal,12pt,draftcls,onecolumn]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: It's difficult to say with so few information about your code and in particular the package used. However, I think you may use the `figure` environnement with `t` as option and put the two graphics inside it.

Comment: You are not meant to reduce the spacing between the image and the caption in a Figure, nor the space between the caption and the remaining text. That's also why the IEEEtran was defined, to standardize these things across conference and journal papers.

Answer (score 2):

I have submitted yesterday a manuscript with something like you describe using IEEEtran. See the second page of the document produced with the following code (Admiral Ackbar not supplied).

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}


% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}
  \title{MWE for subfloat}

\author{Firstname~Lastname~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE}% <-this % stops a space
}

\markboth{IEEE Some Journal,~Vol.~X, No.~X, December~2015}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for IEEE Journals}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Lorem ipsum, dignissium rutrum
\end{IEEEkeywords}


\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle



\section{Introduction}
\lipsum\lipsum
\section{Experimental Results}
\lipsum[1] 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[t!]
  \centering
  \subfloat[It's a trap.\label{fig:top}]{\includegraphics[width=.55\linewidth]{ackbar}}

  \subfloat[It's a trap.\label{fig:bottom}]{\includegraphics[width=.55\linewidth]{ackbar}}
  \caption{Caption for both figures: (a) something on the top; and (b) something on the bottom. Sadly \textbackslash{}subref\{fig:bottom\} throws an exception.}
  \label{fig:top_bottom}
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

[image: The result can be seen here.]

Hope this helps. I think you can pull this one also with subfigure, but you'd need some configuration for not breaking the captions. According to the comments in the bare_jrnl.tex IEEEtran template file, the package subfig and subfloat are the way to go.

Comment: Well done, João. I wonder why the OP didn't accept this answer. It's kind of showing "love" to accept answers that work for you, by the way you lose nothing accepting a correct answer!